# 3.1 update erases customized function page?

Tags: updates

I recently performed the 3.1.1 update on a localhost install, but first performed a backup of my entire wamp directory. Once the install was complete, it seems all the edits to my functions page are now gone. This was my custom post types & taxonomies. I have my backups, so I guess I can just copy and paste. but will I have to do this every time there's an update? Did I perform the update wrong?

Don

Answer (score 2):

Were those updates done to the default Twenty-Ten theme? If so, it was probably steamrolled by the update. Next time, if you are making edits to 'twentyten', go ahead and make a copy of it and save it under a different folder name, then switch to it from 'Appearance->Themes' in the dashboard, it shouldn't be touched by the update again.

Comment: Child theme is preferable imho, you gain all the benefits of the parent theme, including any included in the updates, without having to repeatedly copy the theme and rename it, and you get the same level of control you'd have in using a full blown copy.

Comment: I always develop my own themes so I've never really messed with child themes, just don't know that much about them. I see your point though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using twenty ten, if so when updating WordPress you update twenty ten them and that means that all changes made to the theme files will be lost, and that is why you should use child themes to make changes to any theme.

Comment: Hi Drew and Bainternet,
yes I am working from the 2010 theme for now while I'm amassing the data for the site, but will move on to another theme once it's all in place. I have a pay for theme in mind; is it a good idea to make a child theme from a pay for theme, should I decide to go that direction? thanks for your prompt responses - much appreciated..

Comment: It's a golden rule of mine that if i make any changes (CSS,JS,php or custom page templates) i make a child theme and make the changes there, you never know when a theme will be updated, yes even paid themes, i had so many clients update there themes and overwrite all of the hard work i've done :( so always yes use child themes.

Comment: Backups, Backups, Backups!